# Return value from NodeJS Query, and store the results in a object variable to use on every page

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I'm trying to make a simple page handler for a website (My First NodeJS Project) and struggling to get my head around how to get a MySQL Query to run each time and store the returned data in a variable to be used throughout the application. (I should note I'm using ExpressJS)

Currently in my app.js file I have the following, which seems to be doing it's job at executing for each page load

```
app.use(pageHandler);
```

Inside the pageHandler module, I have the following which queries the database based on the URL of the page.

```
var pageHandler= app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Trying to find details for page: ' + url.parse(req.url).pathname);
    db.query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE page_url = ?", [url.parse(req.url).pathname], function(err, result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
});

module.exports = pageHandler;
```

This does infact print, the successful results on the page, but I'm wanting to store them in a variable wihch I can use throughout the application to get for example the title of the page and whatnot. Currently returns the following from database.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "page_url":"/",
      "title":"Home",
      "meta_title":"First Node Project",
      "meta_description":"Placeholder",
      "meta_keywords":"nodejs, keywords, etc",
      "parent_id":0,
      "position":0,
      "template":"home",
      "content":"Lipsum..."
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Express apps, you can use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) for that:

```
var pageHandler= function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Trying to find details for page: ' + url.parse(req.url).pathname);
    db.query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE page_url = ?", [url.parse(req.url).pathname], function(err, result) {
        res.locals.page = result;
        next();
    });
};

module.exports = pageHandler;
```

This will expose a variable called `page` to your templates, and from other request handlers you can access it as `res.locals.page`.

**EDIT**: from what I understand from your comments, you want to use the above `pageHandler` middleware to dynamically handle page requests. Basically, when a request arrives, it will perform a database lookup against the path name and use the results to render a template.

That's perfectly acceptable, and you can use a normal middleware for that, but since you probably want to limit those requests to `GET` only, here's a more specific implementation:

```
let pageHandler = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Trying to find details for page:', req.path);
  db.query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE page_url = ?", [ req.path ], function(err, result) {
    // Pass errors to Express so it can handle them.
    if (err) return next(err);

    // If there was no matching page, pass the request along.
    if (result.length === 0) return next();

    // Render the template with the page data.
    res.render(YOUR_TEMPLATE, { page : result[0] });
  });
});

// To use:
app.get('*', pageHandler);
```

It also implements proper error handling, and if there wasn't a matching database document for that particular path, it will pass the request to other potential route handlers. And it uses [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path) instead of parsing `req.url`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, really helps - I do have a couple questions though if you don't mind?

I have things printing out in templates and whatnot just fine, but is it possible to use this to actually define the routes in app.js? So I don't have to hard-code each of the routes for all the pages - it can pull them all through from the database based on the page_url and template fields?

Comment: Sure, but how is that different from your original code? It sounds like you want to look up the path name in the database, and render a template based on what the database returns, which seems to me is almost exactly what your original code does (although instead of `res.send(result)` you'd call `res.render()` on a template file).

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do, but from what I currently understand - for each page on your site you need to do something like the following?

`var home = require('./routes/index');`
`app.use('/', home);`

So how would you go about implementing dynamic routes / uses in the app file? Or am I over-complicating the process?

Comment: Thanks a a lot! This is exactly what I was looking to achieve, greatly appreciated!